# lambda capture by value or reference

Tags: python, lambda, python-2.x

I want to know how to capture variable by value and by reference in python.

Lets look at the code.

I have `MyClass` with one property - name and list of instances.

```
from itertools import ifilter

class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

mycl_list = [MyClass("boo"), MyClass("boo"),MyClass("bar"),MyClass("bar")]
```

Next I want to "sort" these instances into dictionary by their values.
The problem is that resulting code returns "bar" instead of "boo".

If I switch `ifilter` to `filter` or `list(ifilter(...))` then resulting output will be "boo".

```
mycl_by_name = {}
for mycl_instance in mycl_list:
  name = mycl_instance.name
  mycl_by_name.setdefault(name, ifilter(lambda _mycl_instance: _mycl_instance.name == name, mycl_list))

for boo_named in mycl_by_name["boo"]:
  print (boo_named.name)
```

From C++ perspective I see the problem in capturing name variable into `ifilter` lambda by reference. So I need to "deepcopy" name variable into `lambda` somehow.

P.S. Yes I know that generator in dictionaty will become exhausted after printing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You cannot capture by value in python.
- You needs to introduce new scope to solve the problem. (yes, in `python` for-loop does not create new scope)

---

```
mycl_by_name = {}
for mycl_instance in mycl_list:
  def f():
    name = mycl_instance.name
    mycl_by_name.setdefault(name, ifilter(lambda _mycl_instance: _mycl_instance.name == name, mycl_list))
  f()

for boo_named in mycl_by_name["boo"]:
  print (boo_named.name)
```